# Encoding/Decoding Unicode and Writing CSV

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I am trying to write words of non-latin based languages to a CSV and cannot get the words to be written in their proper form.

```
foreign='а также'
with open('C:\\Users\\Lance\\Desktop\\Programs\\Database Builder\\Russian Test.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write((foreign).encode('utf-8'))
```

The output of this code is:

Ð° Ñ‚Ð°ÐºÐ¶Ðµ

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It writes the file correctly but you are probably displaying the file using an editor or console that is using `Windows-1252` encoding.

Example from US Windows cmd.exe console:

```
C:\>type "Russian Test.csv"
╨░ ╤é╨░╨║╨╢╨╡
C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>type "Russian Test.csv"
Ð° Ñ‚Ð°ÐºÐ¶Ðµ
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>type "Russian Test.csv"
а также
```

Note: code page 65001 is UTF-8 encoding on Windows.

Since you seem to be using Python 3, you should do this instead and write Unicode strings directly:

```
foreign='а также'
with open('Russian Test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    outfile.write(foreign)
```

Comment: Editor or console or Excel, which doesn't UTF-8 by default, though you can fool it by putting a UTF-8-fake-BOM (U+FEFF) at the start of the file.

Comment: @bobince, or use `utf-8-sig` encoding.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thank you for your response.

I am using python 3 so I implemented you second code display and am still getting the same failed result.

Answer (score 0):

First install `unicodecsv`

```
pip install unicodecsv
```

Then import it in your script

```
import unicodecsv as csv
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

firstly, writing data into csv file depends on csv library, the correct script should be:

```
import csv
with open('path/to/test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in <your_data>:
       writer.writerow(line)
```

secondly, as csv library does not support unicode in python 2x, you need use alternative that handle unicode very well -- https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv, All you have to do is simply installing unicode version of csv library, and adding short import expression at first line:

```
pip install unicodecsv
import unicodecsv as csv
...
```

Remember that convert all your strings into unicode by adding 'u' in front of each string.

Comment: Hi Nicky,

Per your direction:

    import unicodecsv as csv
    import csv

    foreign='а также' 
    with open('C:\\Users\\Lance\\Desktop\\Programs\\Database Builder\\Russian Test.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write((foreign).encode('utf-8'))

Comment: So you're saying if I install unicodecsv and import csv at the beginning of my script that it will work?

Unfortunately, I tried that and I am still getting the same failed result.